# Tensorflow negative sampling

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to follow the udacity tutorial on tensorflow where I came across the following two lines for word embedding models:

```
  # Look up embeddings for inputs.
  embed = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embeddings, train_dataset)
  # Compute the softmax loss, using a sample of the negative labels each time.
  loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sampled_softmax_loss(softmax_weights, softmax_biases, 
                        embed, train_labels, num_sampled, vocabulary_size))
```

Now I understand that the second statement is for sampling negative labels. But the question is how does it know what the negative labels are? All I am providing the second function is the current input and its corresponding labels along with number of labels that I want to (negatively) sample from. Isn't there the risk of sampling from the input set in itself?

This is the full example: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/udacity/5_word2vec.ipynb

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can find the documentation for `tf.nn.sampled_softmax_loss()` [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/sampled_softmax_loss). There is even a good explanation of **Candidate Sampling** provided by TensorFlow [here (pdf)](https://www.tensorflow.org/extras/candidate_sampling.pdf).

---

> How does it know what the negative labels are?

TensorFlow will randomly select negative classes among all the possible classes (for you, all the possible words).

> Isn't there the risk of sampling from the input set in itself?

When you want to compute the softmax probability for your true label, you compute: `logits[true_label] / sum(logits[negative_sampled_labels]`. As the number of classes is huge (the vocabulary size), there is very little probability to sample the true_label as a negative label.
Anyway, I think TensorFlow removes this possibility altogether when randomly sampling. (EDIT: @Alex confirms TensorFlow does this by default)

Comment: "I think TensorFlow removes this possibility altogether when randomly sampling." Correct! There is the flag: `remove_accidental_hits`: A bool. whether to remove "accidental hits" where a sampled class equals one of the target classes. Default is True.`

Comment: Does anyone know a way to provide sampling weights?

Answer (score 2):

[Candidate sampling](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/extras/candidate_sampling.pdf) explains how the sampled loss function is calculated:

- Compute the loss function in a subset *C* of all training samples *L*, where *C = T ⋃ S*, *T* is the samples in target classes, and *S* is the randomly chosen samples in all classes.

The code you provided uses `tf.nn.embedding_lookup` to get the inputs [batch_size, dim] `embed`.

Then it uses `tf.nn.sampled_softmax_loss` to get the sampled loss function:

- softmax_weights:  A Tensor of shape [num_classes, dim].
- softmax_biases: A Tensor of shape [num_classes]. The class biases.
- embed: A Tensor of shape [batch_size, dim].
- train_labels: A Tensor of shape [batch_size, 1]. The target classes *T*.
- num_sampled: An int. The number of classes to randomly sample per batch.  the numbed of classes in *S*.
- vocabulary_size: The number of possible classes.
- sampled_values: default to log_uniform_candidate_sampler

For one batch, the target samples are just `train_labels` (*T*). It chooses `num_sampled` samples from `embed` randomly (*S*) to be negative samples.

It will uniformly sample from `embed` respect to the softmax_wiehgt and softmax_bias. Since `embed` is embeddings[train_dataset] (of shape [batch_size, embedding_size]),  if embeddings[train_dataset[i]] contains train_labels[i], it might be selected back, then it is not negative label.

According to [Candidate sampling](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/extras/candidate_sampling.pdf) page 2, there are different types. For NCE and negative sampling, *NEG=S*, which may contain a part of *T*; for sampled logistic, sampled softmax, *NEG = S-T* explicitly delete *T*.

Indeed, it might be a chance of sampling from train_ set.