# Negative Sampling in Tensorflow without sampled_softmax_loss function

Tags: python, tensorflow, sampling

Is there a function that allow me to do negative sampling without using sampled_softmax_loss ( [Tensorflow negative sampling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37671974/tensorflow-negative-sampling))

I am looking for negative sampling method that takes frequency of a label in training data into training account, and increases chance to negatively sample a word with high frequency.

I found that negative sampling was mentioned by tensorflow official document, but I cannot find any useful implementation in the API:

https://www.tensorflow.org/extras/candidate_sampling.pdf