# How to generate negative samples in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

To give a bit of context, I'm trying to implement a negative sampling scheme in tensorflow similar to the ones used in Personalized Bayesian Ranking and word2vec.

In short, it boils down to obtaining two random samples from a giant sparse matrix -- some samples from the positive entries (i.e. nonzero entries) and the some samples for the negative entries (i.e. zero entries).  I do already have an implementation in raw numpy/scipy (see below).

```
def subsampler(data, num_pos=10, num_neg=10):
    """ Obtain random batch size made up of positive and negative samples

    Parameters
    ----------
    data : scipy.sparse.coo_matrix
       Sparse matrix to obtain random samples from
    num_pos : int
       Number of positive samples
    num_negative : int
       Number of negative samples

    Returns
    -------
    positive_row : np.array
       Row ids of the positive samples
    positive_col : np.array
       Column ids of the positive samples
    positive_data : np.array
       Data values in the positive samples
    negative_row : np.array
       Row ids of the negative samples
    negative_col : np.array
       Column ids of the negative samples

    Note
    ----
    We are not return negative data, since the negative values
    are always zero.
    """
    N, D = data.shape
    y_data = data.data
    y_row = data.row
    y_col = data.col

    # store all of the positive (i, j) coords
    idx = np.vstack((y_row, y_col)).T
    idx = set(map(tuple, idx.tolist()))
    while True:
        # get positive sample
        positive_idx = np.random.choice(len(y_data), num_pos)
        positive_row = y_row[positive_idx].astype(np.int32)
        positive_col = y_col[positive_idx].astype(np.int32)
        positive_data = y_data[positive_idx].astype(np.float32)

        # get negative sample
        negative_row = np.zeros(num_neg, dtype=np.int32)
        negative_col = np.zeros(num_neg, dtype=np.int32)
        for k in range(num_neg):
            i, j = np.random.randint(N), np.random.randint(D)
            while (i, j) in idx:
                i, j = np.random.randint(N), np.random.randint(D)
                negative_row[k] = i
                negative_col[k] = j

        yield (positive_row, positive_col, positive_data,
               negative_row, negative_col)
```

This actually works pretty well - however this proving to be a bit of bottleneck as I try to scale this up to more cores (per this [document](https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/performance_guide), passing in these values `feed_dict` is not easily scalable.)

Now, I realize the tensorflow has really similar samplers premade, such as `tf.nn.uniform_candidate_sampler` and `tf.nn.fixed_unigram_candidate_sampler`.  However, I'm a little tripped up on the documentation, particularly on `tf.nn.uniform_candidate_sampler`.  Its not immediately clear to me at a first glance if this function will explicitly produce negative samples (without any positive samples).  Would this even be the correct function to use?  Or would writing a new C++ op be necessary for this task?

Possibly similar questions have been raised [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49666915/negative-sampling-in-tensorflow-without-sampled-softmax-loss-function) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37671974/tensorflow-negative-sampling)

Answer (score 0):

You could try to implement this almost exactly the way you did in numpy by using the low level TensorFlow [distributions](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/distributions). Most of what is needed is already implemented and since you can use the uniform distribution you can essentially create whatever distribution you want yourself, I do this all the time. For example creating a uniform sampling node and sampling a vector of length N out of it:

```
import tensorflow as tf

N = 100

uni_pdf = tf.distributions.Uniform()
z = uni_pdf.sample(N)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        print(sess.run(z))
```

I can't really say anything about the `tf.nn` samplers, since I do not use them.

Comment: The problem is that this will not have any information about which values correspond to non-zero entries and zero entries -- if I were to use this code out of the box, and try to run tf.gather on the sparse tensor, I'd get errors.  At the end of the day, we need to extinguish from zero values / non-zero values.

Comment: That was just an example supposed to show you how to use Tensorflow distributions. Of course you still have to translate your code into Tensorflow, I don't have the time to do that for you. For random choice you could try something like [random_shuffle](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/random_shuffle) and take the first `n` elements. For distinguishing between zero and non-zero entries simply use [where](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/where).

Comment: Thank you comments.  That doesn't sound trivial ... its not immediately clear how fast you can get this to run via `where` if you are testing for set membership at each iteration (i.e. I don't know how fast set operations are in tensorflow).