# How does sampled_softmax_loss know which embedding to use from the softmax embedding matrix?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to understand this Tensorflow code, which is part of an implementation of the word2vec skip-gram model.

Specifically, I'm trying to understand how sampled_softmax_loss knows which embedding to use from the softmax_weights matrix.

```
with graph.as_default(), tf.device('/cpu:0'):

  # Input data.
  train_dataset = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[batch_size])
  train_labels = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[batch_size, 1])
  valid_dataset = tf.constant(valid_examples, dtype=tf.int32)

  # Variables.
  embeddings = tf.Variable(
    tf.random_uniform([vocabulary_size, embedding_size], -1.0, 1.0))
  softmax_weights = tf.Variable(
    tf.truncated_normal([vocabulary_size, embedding_size],
                         stddev=1.0 / math.sqrt(embedding_size)))
  softmax_biases = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([vocabulary_size]))

  # Model.
  # Look up embeddings for inputs.
  embed = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embeddings, train_dataset)
  # Compute the softmax loss, using a sample of the negative labels each time.
  loss = tf.reduce_mean(
    tf.nn.sampled_softmax_loss(weights=softmax_weights, biases=softmax_biases, inputs=embed, labels=train_labels, num_sampled=num_sampled, num_classes=vocabulary_size))
```

The full code is here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/udacity/5_word2vec.ipynb

The softmax_weights is a matrix in which each row represents the embedding of a particular word (class).

The sampled_softmax_loss is the Tensorflow implementation of negative sampling.

the train_labels used to input the 'labels' is an array of numbers, which can be used as keys to get a word that corresponds to number, and it can also be used as a key to get a particular embedding from the 'embeddings' code above, as seen in the line  "embed = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embeddings, train_dataset)"

I am wondering if sampled_softmax_loss also uses train_labels labels to have each of the numbers correspond to a particular embedding in the softmax_weights, and a particular bias from the softmax_biases? Then it uses random embeddings from the softmax_weights to be used as the negative samples?

This might get flagged as a possible duplicate of [Tensorflow negative sampling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37671974/tensorflow-negative-sampling/37673769)
which basically asks the same questions, but none of the answers specifically answers how it pulls a particular embedding from the softmax_weights and softmax_biases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The embedding lookup only happens for the input - `embed = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embeddings, train_dataset)`. The function `tf.nn.sampled_softmax_loss()` then takes that tensor of shape `[batch_size, embedding_size]` and calculates the sampled softmax of your target label and `num_sampled` random labels.

There is no need on the "output" side to be aware of the embeddings. The only embeddings it cares about are the embeddings corresponding to the inputs.

You can think of `tf.nn.sampled_softmax_loss()` as a single layered neural network with an input of size `embedding_size` and an output of size `1 + num_sampled`. `softmax_weights` and `softmax_biases` are sampled (using [embedding_lookup](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.8/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_impl.py#L1056)) for the true and sampled labels.

Because in word2vec your inputs and output labels are the same, the vector in `softmax_weights` that corresponds to a word can be thought of an additional context embedding for the word. Having the inputs and outputs correspond to the same vocabulary is not required.

The purpose of this is to speed up training. If you had a vocabulary of 1 million words and an embedding size of 10, you would have 2e7 weights to update with each step (1 million x 10 in layer 1 and 10 x 1 million in layer 2). With negative sampling, if you sample 10 negative labels, you only have to update 120 weights for each sample (10 dim embedding + (1 positive + 10 negative) * 10).

Comment: "There is no need on the "output" side to be aware of the embeddings. The only embeddings it cares about are the embeddings corresponding to the inputs." What about for the softmax embeddings? Each word has two embedding representations, one contained in the embeddings matrix (which is used for the center words), the other contained in the `softmax_weights` (which is used for the context words). Since the entire `softmax_weights` is being input into `tf.nn.sampled_softmax_loss()` , there must be some mechanism to only use certain embeddings from the entire matrix.

Comment: Clarified the answer, but `tf.nn.sampled_softmax_loss()` does do an `embedding_lookup` internally.

Comment: "softmax_weights that corresponds to a word can be thought of an additional context embedding for the word". So does `tf.nn.sampled_softmax_loss()` use `labels =` to map a label to a particular column from `softmax_weights` and a particular scaler from  `softmax_biases` ? Or does `tf.nn.sampled_softmax_loss()` do the `embedding_lookup` a different way?

Comment: That is exactly what it does - [see here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.8/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_impl.py#L1056) in the source (the bias embedding lookup is on line 1073). Added a little more clarification to my answer.